# Outputting text in multi lines

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm working on a `reactjs` application and I'm getting a text from the backend which is a multi line text. For example, If I log the text I'm getting it's something like this

```
Gladiator

Enya

Cricket
```

Now I'm trying to display this text as it is in my `reactjs` application like below.

```
 <div>
   <span>{postData.heading}</span>
 </div>
```

With this code I'm getting my output as `Gladiator Enya Cricket` in a single line. How can I display this text in multi lines similar to the way the backend sends it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can replace span to pre, like this:

```
 <div>
   <pre>{postData.heading}</pre>
 </div>
```

Comment: @CraZyDroiD Please accept the answer so that the thread can be closed